# Populate ChoiceField from database

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'd like to have several fields in my form being rendered as ChoiceFields which get their content from the database.

I was thinking something like:

```
class SeriesForm(ModelForm):
  series = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Series.objects.all())

  class Meta:
    model = Series
    exclude = ('model', 'date_added',)
```

But the field `series` is now not appearing at all in my form.  What am I missing?

After trying the solution (using the `ModelChoiceField`), I'm still seeing the same issue. Here is my code:

```
series = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Series.objects.values('series'), 
  empty_label="     ")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`ModelChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) instead.

Comment: @Ignacio It's more helpful for users if you actually solve the user's problem in the answer, instead of linking to a site that could move or change the URLs, rendering your answer useless.

Comment: Agreed, an example with passing parameter for queryset could be very helpful

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this to get data directly from the database without a model?